# CS:GO Stats Api [GetUserStatsForGame]

Tags: php, api, steam

I got a problem with the GetUserStatsForGame Api. I used 
`http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUserStats/GetUserStatsForGame/v0002/?appid=730&key=<<KEY>>&steamid=<<PROFILEID>>`.

How can i get the the playerstats?

I already tried this but it dosent work :/

```
 if(!$_SESSION['steamid'] == ""){
    include("settings.php");
    if (empty($_SESSION['steam_uptodate']) or $_SESSION['steam_uptodate'] == false or empty($_SESSION['steam_personaname'])) {

        @ $url = file_get_contents("http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUserStats/GetUserStatsForGame/v0002/?appid=730&key=".$steamauth['apikey']."&steamids=".$_SESSION['steamid']);
        $content = json_decode($url, true);
        $_SESSION['total_kills'] = $content['playerstats']['stats']['total_kills'][0]['value'];
        $_SESSION['steam_steamid'] = $content['response']['players'][0]['steamid'];


}

    $csgoprofile['total_kills'] = $_SESSION['total_kills'];
}
```

Please help!

Comment: What does the output JSON look like? Quick guess, should `$content['playerstats'][..` be `$content['response']['playerstats'][..`?

Comment: `{
 "playerstats": {
  "steamID": "17343684926432",
  "gameName": "ValveTestApp260",
  "stats": [
   {
    "name": "total_kills",
    "value": 41269
   },
   {
    "name": "total_deaths",
    "value": 41720
   },`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stats` is a list of `name`/`value` pairs so `$content['playerstats']['stats']['total_kills']` isn't going to work.

The path to the total_kills value is `$content['playerstats']['stats'][0]['value']` but you can't rely on `total_kills` being at `0`.

You can do:

```
$key = null;
foreach ($content['playerstats']['stats'] as $key => $stat) {
    if ($stat["name"] === "total_kills") {
        $key = $index;
    }
}

$total_kills = $content['playerstats']['stats'][$key]['value'];
```

If you also want to read the other stats you could do something like:

```
$stats = array();
foreach ($content['playerstats']['stats'] as $stat) {
    $stats[$stat["name"]] = $stat["value"];
}

$total_kills = $stats["total_kills"];
$total_deaths = $stats["total_deaths"];
```

Comment: Thank you verry much but i get no output. Any idea?

Comment: What output are you expecting? Make sure you're got error reporting turned on (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php) so you can see any error messages.

Comment: Its not an error (btw i got it turned on). And i expect an output like this: `<?php  echo "" . $total_kills . "</br>"; ?>`

Comment: Ok i made it. Thank you verry much (^_^)